# What 12 tribes are meant in many places while there really were 13?

Tags: number, shevatim-12-tribes

There are many mentions of the "12 tribes" (e.g., the tag of this question). But there really were 13: Ya'akov had 12 sons, of which each was the ancestor of one tribe except Yosef that was the ancestor of 2.

I know that there were 12 tribal territories because Levi had no land of its own. But on the other hand, Levi had its own symbol while Yosef only had one symbol (see [question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23496/what-are-the-symbols-of-the-12-tribes) and [picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Mosaic_Tribes.jpg)). But AFAIK nobody ever mentions a "Yosef tribe".

So what **12** tribes are usually meant?

Comment: And what about cohanim?

Comment: Cohanim are part of the Levi tribe.

Comment: Ephraim and Menashe are part of the Yosef tribe.

Answer (score 4):

As you note in the question, sometimes *Levi* is excluded (and *Yosef* split up) and sometimes *Levi* is included (as is *Yosef*). Thus, there are two divisions into twelve tribes each. Other examples — you mention the divvying up of the land and the tribal symbols — are the post-exodus desert travels (which was by tribe, with *Yosef* split and with *Levi* excluded from the configuration) and the blessings of *Yaakov* and *Moshe* (at the ends of Genesis and Deuteronomy, respectively, where *Yosef* was not split and *Levi* was included). I can't think of any situation in which all thirteen potential tribes (including *Levi*, *Efrayim*, and *M'nashe*) are included simultaneously. This explains the common reference to "twelve tribes". So your question "what 12 tribes are usually meant?" has, I think, no answer: either of the two possibilities, depending on context.

Comment: "I can't think of any situation in which all thirteen potential tribes (including Levi, Efrayim, and M'nashe) are included simultaneously." See Deuteronomy 33:6 and the Ramban on it.