# Tribe Plates on door of Heichal Shlomo

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, art

On the door of the Heichal Shlomo in Jerusalem are several square plates which appear to symbolize the twelve tribes.

[image: היכל שלמה סמלי השבטים כניסה]

I'm having trouble figuring out which tribe each of these plates corresponds to.  Perhaps I would have an easier time if I understood the Hebrew titles on the images.  Several (but not all) of the images appear to be based on the imagery from the blessings Jacob gives his sons in [Genesis 49](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+49&version=ESV).

Here are the ones I believe I have identified...

#### Levi (ephod)

[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט לוי]

Genesis 49 doesn't mention ephods or the priestly nature of Levi, but I think this one is clear, regardless.

#### Judah (lion)

[image: היכל שלמה שבט יהודה]

#### Zebulun (ship)

[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט זבולון]

#### Issachar (donkey)

[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט יששכר]

#### Dan (serpent)

[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט דן]

#### Asher (rich food)

Left-most plate in the below image:

[image: אריה בין סמלי השבטים]

#### Naphtali (deer)

[image: היכל שלמה שבט נפתלי]

#### Benjamin (wolf)

[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט בנימין]

Have I misidentified any of the above images?

#### Unidentified tribes & plates

So, that leaves Reuben, Simeon, Gad, and Joseph, and the following plates which don't seem to line up with the imagery in Genesis 49:

[image: היכל שלמה שבט אפרים]
[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט שמעון]
[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט ראובן]
[image: היכל שלמה סמל שבט גד]

Which plate goes with which tribe, and why?

---

Thanks to [zeevveez](https://www.flickr.com/photos/zeevveez/) for the great [CC BY 2.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/) pictures!

Comment: Did you look at the title of the images?

Comment: I bet the Reuven one is Dudaim.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! I'll bet you can find the information you want in the answers to [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23496/what-are-the-symbols-of-the-12-tribes).

Comment: Shimon is the city gates

Comment: @DoubleAA, you're right.  I don't know Hebrew, but Google Translate appears to do a decent job with the names in the image titles.

Comment: @IsaacMoses - that is excellent information!  Thanks for the link!

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but is "ephod" even the correct term, or is the thing that is pictured for Levi something else?

Comment: @DanielSchilling , Choshen

Comment: Is it possible to list the artist who created the door plates and from where did he receive the original images ( images before the door plate)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left to Right:  Bow and Arrow with sheaves of wheat and ox at top (Ephraim/Joseph);  Arched building/ castle (maybe referring to the Shechemite kingdom where Simeon led the revolt to rescue his sister Dina from the rapist prince (Shimon/Simeon);  Mandrakes (Reuven/Reuben);  tents (Gad).

Comment: Thanks for explaining the images! That's exactly what I was looking for. Your answer helped me find this website: https://karinforeman.com/description-of-gad-%D7%92%D6%B8%D6%BC%D7%93/ ... and elaborating on your answer a bit, on Joseph's plate the sheaves of wheat are bowing over, representing the dream he had. Reuben found mandrakes in the field and brought them to his mother. Without your answer I had no idea that those were mandrakes in the picture. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As @DoubleAA suggested, the answer is on the pictures "web title", which I see when resting the mouse on each image.

From right to left, you have Gad, Re'uven, Shimon and Ephraim. You don't have a pic for Menashe.